# How to receive a sound alert for e mail on iPhone 8+

Tags: iphone

I went to settings added sound I wanted The email only updates when I open folder I want an alert the same as iMessage which is when they arrive even if my phone is sleeping

Answer (score 3):

Mail push/fetch is disabled in Low Power Mode, so you can't get an alert if you have that on.

To configure Mail push or fetch, go to Settings → Accounts & Passwords → Fetch New Data and set your accounts to Push (if available) or Fetch instead of Manual. Fetch is only available on power and Wi-Fi so if you do not meet this criteria it will act as Manual anyway.

Comment: Additionally if using fetch be sure to scroll down and set the fetch frequency.  After that head over to Settings > Notifications and verify badge and banner settings.  I haven’t added a new email in awhile, but at one time Mail was a sound only, I don’t know current defaults for mail accounts.